# Create backup of postgresql via ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, postgresql, processbuilder

I want to create a backup of my database using pg_dump in java. The creation of backup works fine, but it doesn't start before the program exits.

Is there any way to start the backup instantly?

```
public static void backupDb() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String path = "C:\\HACENE\\test.backup";
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  //PostgreSQL variables    
  String host = "localhost";
  String user = "postgres";
  String dbase = "gtr_bd";
  String password = "postgres";
  Process p;
  ProcessBuilder pb;

  r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dump", "-v", "-h", host, "-f", path, "-U", user, dbase);
  pb.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", password);
  pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
  p = pb.start();
  System.out.println("end of backup");
}
```

Comment: `p.waitFor()` perhaps?

Comment: The behaviour is depending on the OS environment in place. Process execution is not done by java itself. Thus, it is up to the OS to actually execute the process you defined and handed over for execution. Also How long is _not before the pprogramme exit_ (milli seconds, seconds, hours)?

Comment: the process is handled by the os , so logically it should start when i launch it from the application , but the process start exactely when i exit from the program

Answer (score 0):

You should check the state of the `Process` instance returned from `ProcessBuilder.start()`. As already mentioned in the comments you can use the `Process.waitFor()` method to wait for the process to finish. Furthermore you should consider inspecting the exit value of the started process to determine if your backup was successful or not.

This is what I did in a project of mine:

```
private void validateExitValue(final Process aProcess, final String aCommand,
    final String aResult) throws IllegalStateException {
    do {
        try {
            if (aProcess.waitFor() != 0) {
                final String errorMessage = String.format("Command '%s' terminated with exit status '%s': %s",
                    aCommand, aProcess.exitValue(), aResult);
                throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
            }
            break;
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

This method will wait for the process to finish and throw an `IllegalStateException`, if the process finished with an exit code other than `0`.

The observation that the backup process currently is started just as your Java program terminates is just by coincidence I suspect, as starting the backup process is very likely the last action that is performed by your Java program. Starting the external process will take some time and your program continues and terminates, that is it looks like the the process is being started at termination of the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Comment -> p = pb.start();
// add this at the end:

final Process process = pb.start();  
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();  
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
// because you put "-v" in your command. Another way is to remove "-v" from your command
```

-v Specifies verbose mode. This will cause pg_dump to output detailed object comments and start/stop times to the dump file, and progress messages to standard error. From this [LINK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this command in cmd this work fine:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 database_name > "C:\Test\test.buckup"
```

So you can put this lines in a .bat file like this:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\" 
pg_dump.exe -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 bd_suivi > "C:\Test\test.buckup"
exit
```

And execute this file.bat with java, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start script.bat");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("I finished the creation of the buckup!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
    }
}
```

good luck.